# Trying to search globally with Telethon iter_messages yields no results

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using Telethon python package for the Telegram API.

Using the following code, I can collect messages for a particular user, based on a keyword search:

```
import config
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
import datetime
import asyncio


api_id = config.telegram_crawler_secrets_and_settings['TELEGRAM_API_ID']
api_hash = config.telegram_crawler_secrets_and_settings['TELEGRAM_API_HASH']
phone = config.telegram_crawler_secrets_and_settings['TELEGRAM_API_PHONE_NUMBER']


async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        async for message in client.iter_messages(5067150042, limit=10, search='hello', wait_time=0):
            print(message.stringify())
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)


asyncio.run(main())
```

According to [this post](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/920), it should be possible to replace the entity (User ID) with `None` and perform a global search across public channels, however it does not appear to work in my attempts (see below).

```
async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        async for message in client.iter_messages(None, limit=10, search='hello', wait_time=0):
            print(message.stringify())
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and this works for me:

```
async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        async for message in client.iter_messages(None, limit=10, search='hello', wait_time=0):
            print(message.stringify())
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)


asyncio.run(main())
```

if it still doesnt work for you, please provide Error message you get.

Comment: thanks for the reply. with this method, I still get no results (+ no error message either)

Comment: Hmm thats strange. If you havent provided all the code in your question, feel free to post the rest so i could take a look. I tried my answer on my own telegram and it worked as you wanted. Hope i can help you out!

Comment: thanks for getting back, I've just updated my original post with the full code! I'm also running the latest package version of Telethon. Strange it works when I pass a client_id, but getting no results with `None`

Comment: This is very strange. i copied all ur code and still works fine for me. What if you try with a different session name?

Comment: if that doesnt work, try to reinstall the telethon library

Comment: OK, created a new session file, fresh telethon installation on a clean conda environment and still nothing prints when using `None`.. How odd!

Comment: what version of Telethon do you use? i have version 1.24.0

Comment: yes, same: Telethon 1.24.0

Comment: At this point i would suggest trying a new tg API or even computer,  this issue annoys me peobably as much as it annoys you LOL

Comment: yes, I will do! thanks for the help, I'll report back if I find any other ways..